# Groovy script not able to execute external process

Tags: python, command-line, groovy

I'm trying to execute a python external process from my Groovy script but it doesn't produce any output.

So as a small sanity test I tried simply outputting the python version:

```
    def command = """ /usr/local/bin/python -V """
    def proc = command.execute()
    proc.waitFor()
    println "This is output: " + proc?.in?.text
```

The above doesn't produce any output, however, from my command line I AM able to run `/usr/local/bin/python -V`

What is weird is that if I modify the script to run `identify` then it does produce an output.

```
    def command = """ /usr/local/bin/identify --version """
    def proc = command.execute()
    proc.waitFor()
    println "This is output: " + proc?.in?.text
```

What can be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`python -V` command prints the version number to standard error instead of standard output.

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.8
$ python -V 2>/dev/null
$
```

So, to get the output, redirect the stderr (2) to stdout (1):

```
def command = """ /usr/local/bin/python -V 2>&1 """
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()
println "This is output: " + proc?.in?.text
```

Alternatively, you can use [`err`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html#getErr()) instead of `in` to get standard error output:

```
def command = """ /usr/bin/python -V """
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()
println "This is output: " + proc?.err?.text
```

Comment: wow, would have never known that. my python script outputs something using `print "something" ` that was not working thats why I tried `-V`. would that be printing to stdout as well?

Comment: `print` statement (function in PYthon 3.x) will print the message to stdout unless you use `>> sys.stderr` (or `file=sys.stderr` in Python 3.x)